# Check date range with an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array, in which I have inserted some day that are holidays.

In my app I choose an interval (startDate and endDate) and I should check that this interval is not in my array. How can I do?

For example:

```
holidaysArray = [
"2020-04-12",
            "2020-04-13",
            "*-03-17",
            "*-05-01",
            "*-06-02"
}
```

I choose as

> ```
> startDate:  2022-03-15T16:16:00.000Z 
> endDate:2022-03-18T16:12:23.103Z
> ```

**What I expect**

So now I should count the day between the startDate and EndDate, and the result is 4 days. But I my array there is value "*-03-17", so I should not considering a day.

How can I do?

I have a datepicker:

```
<DatePicker
            modal
            open={showStartDate}
            date={startDate}
            title={null}
            confirmText="Ok"
            cancelText="Cancel"
            mode="date"
            onConfirm={(date) => {
              setShowStartDate(false)
              onChangeStart( date)
            }}
            onCancel={() => setShowStartDate(false)}
          />

<DatePicker
            modal
            open={showEndDate}
            date={endDate}
            title={null}
            confirmText="Ok"
            cancelText="Cancel"
            mode="date"
            onConfirm={(date) => {
              setShowEndDate(false)
              onChangeStart( date)
            }}
            onCancel={() => setShowEndDate(false)}
          />
```

So my

```
onChangeStart = (selectedDate) => {
   checkDate(selectedDate, endDate)
}

checkDate = (start, end) => {
  const holidayArray = travelInfo.time.holidayArray
  //
}
```

Comment: yes for example *-01-01 it the first of january of all years

Comment: Can you have fab-29 as a holiday, something that comes every 4 years?

Comment: If the feb-29 will be an holiday it will be put in the array. I should control the array date

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over 'holidayArray' you need to check if the holiday falls between the selected date, if it does just decrement the total difference between the dates by '1' (assuming you are counting Sundays' as well).
For the case where the dates have `*`, you need to find the 'years' that can fall between the dates and use them to replace the `*` to form the appropriate date.

First Step (Find year (or years if the selection is too large, just in case))

(assuming endDate > startDate)

```
const findYears = (startDate, endDate) => {
    let yearsArray = [];
    let endYear = parseInt(endDate?.split("-")[0]);
    let startYear= parseInt(startDate?.split("-")[0]);
    yearsArray.push(endYear);
    while(endYear !== startYear){
         endYear--;
         yearsArray.push(endYear);
    }
  return yearsArray;
}
```

Now complete your `checkDate` function

```
checkDate = (start, end) => {
    const years = findYears(start, end)
    const holidayArray = travelInfo.time.holidayArray;
    var from = new Date(start);
    var to = new Date(end);
    var diff = 0;
    holidayArray.forEach(holiday => {
        if (holiday.match("\\*")) {
            years.forEach(year => {
                var check = new Date(holiday.replace("\\*", year));
                if (check > from && check < to) {
                    diff--
                }
            })
        } else {
            var check = new Date(holiday);
            if (check > from && check < to) {
                diff--
            }
        }
    })
    const diffTime = Math.abs(start - end);
    var diffDays = Math.round(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return diffDays + diff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried your version but I receive error in the split in FindYear

Comment: @Jack23 I meant to post this code as an algorithm and did not intend it as code for copy/paste. I made it detailed for you to understand it better. Obviously you need to tweak it as per your code. `findYears` function is written assuming the dates are in format : `yyyy-dd-mm-*`. `var startDate = "2022-03-15T16:16:00.000Z",
    endDate= "2023-03-18T16:12:23.103Z";` gives: `[ 2023, 2022 ]`

Please make sure you debug these functions if you are getting error from them.(check for null, undefined, and other date formats.)